# Как написать тест junit?

Tags: java, junit

Подскажите как написать тест для метода создания файла?
Вот метод:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public FileResponse create(FileObjDTO fileObjDTO) {
    FileObj fileObj = dbFileService.create(fileObjDTO);
    fileObj.getId().toString());
    minioService.putObjectIntoTheBucket(bucketName, getInputStreamForFileObjDto(fileObjDTO),
            fileObj.getId().toString());
    getInputStreamForFileObjDto(fileObjDTO), fileObj);
    fileObjDTO = objectMapper.fileToFileObjDTO(fileObj);
    FileResponse fileResponse = new FileResponse();
    fileResponse.setMessage("");
    fileResponse.setSuccess(true);
    fileResponse.getFileObjPages().add(fileObjDTO);
    return fileResponse;
}
```

А вот мой тест-метод:

```
@Test
public void testCreate1() {
    System.out.println("create");
    FileObjDTO fileObjDTO = new FileObjDTO();
    FileServiceImpl instance = new FileServiceImpl((DbFileService) dbFileService.create(fileObjDTO), 
    minioService, objectMapper);
    FileResponse expResult = new FileResponse();
    FileResponse result = instance.create(fileObjDTO);
    Assert.assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

При запуске теста получаю:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.smclinic.files.entity.model.owner.Owner.<init>(Owner.java:37)
at ru.smclinic.files.entity.model.storage.FileObj.<init>(FileObj.java:70)
at ru.smclinic.files.config.ObjectMapperConfig$1.fileToFileObj(ObjectMapperConfig.java:27)
at ru.smclinic.files.service.dbFileService.impl.DbFileServiceImpl.create(DbFileServiceImpl.java:71)
at ru.smclinic.files.DbFileServiceTest.testCreate1(DbFileServiceTest.java:184)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: `dbFileService` - чему равна эта переменная на момент выполнения теста? и что на выходе даёт её метод `create` ?

Comment: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. fileObjDTO все поля null

Comment: dbFileService = DBFileServiceImpl@1476